# Text issues with Abspath

Tags: python, file, syntax-error, os.path

I've been using
`CURRENT_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and it has been working well.

However, for whatever reason when I have any path with a `/N` such as

```
tk.PhotoImage(f'{CURRENT_DIR}\Library\Images\NA_notes.png')
```

or

```
wb.open_new(f'{CURRENT_DIR}\Library\PD\Vender\No Hold Open\DOOR.pdf')
```

I get:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: malformed \N character escape

It gets fixed if I just change the `/N` to `/n`

The problem is I have hundreds of these instances within a ton of folders, so is there any way to fix this without having to change every single folder name?

Comment: Did you try escaping all ```\``` with ```\\```? Something like `tk.PhotoImage(f'{CURRENT_DIR}\\Library\\Images\\NA_notes.png')`

Comment: Just did, and works like a charm now! Thank you! You just saved my sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping your location as `\` is used for several escape sequence characters. You can do this by replacing `\` with `\\`. Some thing like this:

```
tk.PhotoImage(f'{CURRENT_DIR}\\Library\\Images\\NA_notes.png')
wb.open_new(f'{CURRENT_DIR}\\Library\\PD\\Vender\\No Hold Open\\DOOR.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change path then simply say to python it's raw string.

```
print(fr'{CURRENT_DIR}\Library\Images\NA_notes.png')
```